# How to create LOV with font awesome icons in Oracle APEX app?

Tags: font-awesome, lov, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created an LOV in my application. I want add font awesome icons and colors to this list for per list rows. But I don't know how to do it. May anyone help me with that?

[You can see what i want to do by this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClnLZ.png)

Comment: Hi, did you find solution to your problem?

Comment: I have tried something but I can't find any solution yet.

Comment: Where are your planning to use this LOV, select page item or as as navigation links

Comment: This will just be a list that I'll use to select the page item. Such as the priority list, the status list.

Answer (score 0):

**Shared Components > Lists** should work for you. Lists can have dynamic or static source like LOVs and also option to specify font awesome icons.

Following blog article by John Snyders describes how to implement Custom Menus in APEX 5

http://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2015/07/13/apex-5-0-custom-menus